# Javascript arrays remaining identical after one is changed

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am making an app in which an algorithm is run on an array. Because the contents of the array will change during the execution of the algorithm, I'm storing the array contents to another array beforehand - performing the 'if' statements on the source array but updating the temporary array, then equating them afterwards.

The problem is that after running the algorithm, the two arrays are still identical. It seems that updating the temporary array automatically updates the source array.

I've created [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bYnm3/) to demonstrate:

```
var a = new Array( 0 , 1 , 2 );
var b = a;

b[1]=3;

document.write( (a[1]==b[1]) );

//Should show 'false' as this will not be correct
```

The code above returns "True". Is this normal behaviour? How can I overcome this?

Comment: Both variables refer to the same array. In order to clone an array into a second variable, do `var b = a.slice();`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is normal behaviour, when copying array you are actually making a reference, so when you do `var b = a` that means instead of copying value you are just copying the reference

if you want to shallow copy an array (array with only one depth level) then you can use simple method like this:

```
var b = a.slice(0);
```

But if you want to deep copy an array (array with 2 or more depth level) then you can use below method for that:

```
var objClone = function(srcObj) {
  var destObj = (this instanceof Array) ? [] : {};
  for (var i in srcObj)
  {
     if (srcObj[i] && typeof srcObj[i] == "object") {
         destObj[i] = objClone(srcObj[i]);
     } else {
         destObj[i] = srcObj[i];
     }
  }

  return destObj;
};
```

For use of both of these methods check [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E7yW6/1/)

Comment: This works in the jsfiddle, but not on my actual application. I'm using 2-dimensional arrays - does this affect the slice?

Comment: @TheTurkey `.slice()` performs a shallow clone. If you want a full (deep) clone, you'll need a custom function (e.g. jQuery provides this functionality).

Comment: thanks @Šime Vidas i have updated the answer for deep cloning also

Answer (score 3):

`b = a` doesn't copy the array, but a reference. Use `b = a.slice()` to make a copy.

[**See also ...**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Comment: "*Array named a*" - the array doesn't have a name. "a" is the name of the variable that refers to the array.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned `a = b` does not copy the array. However, if you do end up using the `.slice()` method to copy arrays please note that objects within an array will be copied by reference.

Take the following example

```
var obj = { greeting: "hello world" };

var a = [ obj ];
var b = a;

a[0].greeting = "foo bar";
b[0].greeting // => "foo bar";
```

Other than that you are good to go :)